# AngularJS failed to instantiate zingchart module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, mean.io

I'm building a web app using mean.io stack. I'm trying to add a 'zingchart-angularjs' dependency and I am getting this error:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'zingchart-angularjs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I'm new to angular so I'm confused why I could get the 'ngMaterial' dependency working just fine but not the zingchart dependency.

Can someone point me in the right direction/describe what I am doing wrong?

Here is my js file -- dashboard.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

/* jshint -W098 */

function DashboardController($scope, Global, Dashboard, $stateParams) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.package = {
        name: 'dashboard'
    };
}

angular
    .module('mean.dashboard', ['ngMaterial', 'zingchart-angularjs'])
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Global', 'Dashboard', '$stateParams'];

})();
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-material.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="mean.dashboard" layout="row" ng-cloak>

  <div class="container" layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-whiteframe-10dp" md-is-locked-open='true'>
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item>
          <md-button>
            Dashboard
          </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content id="content" flex>
      <ng-view>
        <zingchart id="myChart" zc-json="myJson" zc-height=500 zc-width=600></zingchart>
      </ng-view>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put your `index.html` to see how you include the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.html` you need to include the `zingchart-angularjs` `script` before the `dashboard.js` one;

Also, I don't see the `angular-material` `scripts` in your `index.html` for `ngMaterial`:

I added this to `index.html` and it works perfect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-aria.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-material.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/angular/material

Comment: getting a completely blank page when i open it in the browser

Comment: That works for me, I see a button that says `Dashboard home` and no error in `console`

Comment: maybe you are misunderstanding.  its only when i add the 'zingchart-angularjs' dependency to my dashboard.js file that the browser is blank.  If i remove that dependency so its only angular
    .module('mean.dashboard', ['ngMaterial'])...  then i have the dashboard rendering in the browser....

as per step 2 of this documentation https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS

Comment: Nop, I understood perfectly. When I tested your code I saw this error: `[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available!` and it was because you don't have the `ngMaterial` scripts in your `index.html`, then I added the scripts and it works OK, I don't see that error nor the `zingchart-js` one and I see the button in the browser.

Comment: should i mention im using bower.  Isnt the point of that so I dont need to include the dependencies in my html?

Comment: Bower is a package manager, maybe you are using a gulp.js or grunt.js task for bundling your bower_components, and if that is the case, you need to check that you have included `zingchart` before your app code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146331/discussion-between-harry-and-luisenrike).